# Latex implementation problem with matplotlib/python: RuntimeError: Latex command not found

Tags: python, matplotlib, latex

I want to use latex for my labels in my matplotlib figures. I'm using Mac OS X and thonny. I downloaded a test program but every time I get the error:

> RuntimeError: Latex command not found. Install 'xelatex' or change pgf.texsystem to the desired command.

I think it's a path error...

I also tried to change the path

```
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin'
```

I get this error instead:

> kpathsea:make_tex: Invalid filename `DejaVu Serif', contains ' '
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   /Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/**init**.py:886: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: 
>   examples.directory is deprecated; in the future, examples will be found relative to the 'datapath' directory.
>     "found relative to the 'datapath' directory.".format(key))
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Users/Marten/Downloads/pgf_preamble_sgskip.py", line 33, in 
>       plt.tight_layout(.5)
>     File "/Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 1382, in tight_layout
>       gcf().tight_layout(pad=pad, h_pad=h_pad, w_pad=w_pad, rect=rect)
>     File "/Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/figure.py", line 2370, in tight_layout
>       renderer = get_renderer(self)
>     File "/Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/tight_layout.py", line 228, in get_renderer
>       renderer = canvas.get_renderer()
>     File "/Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 946, in get_renderer
>       return RendererPgf(self.figure, None, dummy=True)
>     File "/Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 393, in **init**
>       self.latexManager = LatexManagerFactory.get_latex_manager()
>     File "/Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 208, in get_latex_manager
>       new_inst = LatexManager()
>     File "/Users/Marten/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/matplotlib/backends/backend_pgf.py", line 290, in **init**
>       "or error in preamble:\n%s" % stdout)
>   matplotlib.backends.backend_pgf.LatexError: LaTeX returned an error, probably missing font or error in preamble:
>   b'This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.99999 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=xelatex)\n restricted \write18 enabled.\n**entering extended mode\nLaTeX2e <2018-04-01> patch level 2\nBabel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.\n\n*(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/minimal.cls\nDocument Class: minimal 2001/05/25 Standard LaTeX minimal class\n)\n*(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/units.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ifthen.sty)\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/units/nicefrac.sty))\n*(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/metalogo/metalogo.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphicx.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty)\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/graphics.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/trig.sty)\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-cfg/graphics.cfg)\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics-def/xetex.def)))\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/xparse/xparse.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/expl3-code.tex)\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3xdvipdfmx.def)))\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec-xetex.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fontenc.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/tuenc.def))\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/fontspec/fontspec.cfg))))\n*(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-xetex.s\nty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/l3packages/l3keys2e/l3keys2e.sty)\n (/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/filehook/filehook.sty)\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/fix-cm.sty\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))\n(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/unicode-math/unicode-math-table.t\nex)))\n*\n!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!\n!\n! fontspec error: "font-not-found"\n! \n! The font "DejaVu Serif" cannot be found.\n! \n! See the fontspec documentation for further information.\n! \n! For immediate help type H .\n!...............................................  \n                                                  \n<*> \setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}\n                              \nNo pages of output.\nTranscript written on texput.log.\n'

## Test Program:

```
import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use("pgf")
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import os
os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin'

plt.rcParams.update({
    "font.family": "serif",  # use serif/main font for text elements
    "text.usetex": True,     # use inline math for ticks
    "pgf.rcfonts": False,    # don't setup fonts from rc parameters
    "pgf.texsystem" : "xelatex",
    "pgf.preamble": [
         "\\usepackage{units}",          # load additional packages
         "\\usepackage{metalogo}",
         "\\usepackage{unicode-math}",   # unicode math setup
         r"\setmathfont{xits-math.otf}",
         r"\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}",  # serif font via preamble
         ]
})

plt.figure(figsize=(4.5, 2.5))
plt.plot(range(5))
plt.xlabel("unicode text: я, ψ, €, ü, \\unitfrac[10]{°}{µm}")
plt.ylabel("\\XeLaTeX")
plt.legend(["unicode math: $λ=∑_i^∞ μ_i^2$"])
plt.tight_layout(.5)

plt.savefig("pgf_preamble.pdf")
plt.savefig("pgf_preamble.png")
```

Comment: It's weird that your installation didn't deal with the `PATH` properly. Anyways, regarding your second error, it's likely because you're using `xelatex` specific packages. So change the line `"pgf.texsystem" : "pdflatex",` into `"pgf.texsystem" : "xelatex",`.

Comment: Yeah xelatex is the default value. It is the same error with xelatex so I tried pdflatex, but it is the same. So i can start xelatex with the terminal from any direction if that helps ... :/

Comment: I'm pretty sure the second error you obtain comes from you using `pdflatex` instead of `xelatex`. Can you please run you program with `"pgf.texsystem" : "xelatex",` and edit your answer to include the _full error message?_

Comment: So I edited and put the complete error in. I tried also to comment out the dejavu serif and I get different error 
`RuntimeError: No suitable pdf to png renderer found.`

Comment: The problem is now clear: latex can't find the `DejaVu Serif` font... so either this font isn't installed on your system, or  there's something wrong with your texlive installation (or the way you call this python script). Can you compile, with `xelatex`, the following? (save it in a file, say `test.tex` and run `xelatex test.tex`): `\documentclass{minimal}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Serif}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}`

Comment: So i tried a different test program with `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)' and
'plt.rc('font', family='serif')` without an extra preamble. And that works when I add the path `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin'`. So problem is solved in a different way, but thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

So i tried a different test program with `plt.rc('text', usetex=True)` and `plt.rc('font', family='serif')` without an extra preamble. And that works when I add the path `os.environ["PATH"] += os.pathsep + '/usr/local/texlive/2018/bin/x86_64-darwin'`. So problem is solved in a different way. – madden994 just now   edit